# Numbered Definitions, Theorems in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, theorems

How to get numbered Lemmas, Definitions, Theorems and so on in `beamer`?

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set the `theorems` template with the `numbered` option:

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
```

or with the `ams style` option:

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
```

If additionally you use the `envcountsect` class option by loading `beamer` in the following way:

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
```

then theorems, definitions, and so on to be numbered locally to each *section* (by default they are numbered consecutively throughout the presentation).

Comment: Apparently, I'm facing the problem that the all the definitions and theorems are counted together.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, please help

Comment: @Eduard - Page 32 of the user guide of the [beamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package has the following to say on this subject: "If you do number theorems and definitions, number everything consecutively. Thus if there are one theorem, one lemma, and one definition, you would have Theorem 1, Lemma 2, and Definition 3. Some people prefer all three to be numbered 1. We would *strongly* like to discourage this. The problem is that this makes it virtually impossible to find anything since Theorem 2 might come after Definition 10 or the other way round."