# \newtheorem not numbering in beamer latex

Tags: beamer, newtheorem

I've been working in a beamer file, and I'm using the `\newthorem` command to create an environment for definitions but the problem is that my definitions are not numbered.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{frame}
\begin{defi}
Some definition %This is expected to be numbered but it's not
\end{defi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66655/numbered-definitions-theorems-in-beamer