# beamer definition numbered

Tags: beamer, block, definition

I would like to display a definition block in beamer (I'm preparing some slides) but block should be numbered, something link "Definition 1", "Definition 2", etc.
Using the code below, it always writes "Definition"

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    %\framesubtitle{subtitle}
    \begin{definition}
      This is the first definition
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}
      This is the second definition
    \end{definition}

\end{frame}
```

There is similar question already answered in this forum [Numbered Definitions, Theorems in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66655/numbered-definitions-theorems-in-beamer), but it refers to theorems and not definitions. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numbered Definitions, Theorems in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66655/5001)

Comment: The answer that you linked talks about theorems, not definitions..

Comment: That answer pertains to *all* theorem-like environments, *including* `definition` environments.